# RequestFactory is null inside Confluence Custom Seraph Authenticator

Tags: atlassian-plugin-sdk

This is a copy of a question I asked on the [Atlassian forums](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Questions/Seraph-Can-t-get-SAL-for-remote-Service-Call/qaq-p/690444)

I've been trying to make my own custom authentication plugin for SSO with my company using `Seraph` in `Confluence` (And will late do so in Jira) but I can't seem to make remote Service calls because I can't find the `RequestFactory SAL`.

Here are the rough steps I've taken so far:

1. Download/Setup SDK
2. Create Confluence Plugin
3. Extended the ConfluenceAuthenticator class and implemented my own logic

Now I'm trying to get a reference to the `RequestFactory SAL` and have tried,

1. Dependency injection with annotations
2. [Dependency injection with contructor](https://developer.atlassian.com/plugins/scroll-viewport/draft/7F000101014A533132D9CDB212BD5E1B/atlassian-platform-common-components/shared-access-layer/sal-services?_ga=2.118831945.1150382858.1513224618-214217918.1488747972)
3. `ComponentLocator`
4. `component-import` xml tag (docs are out of date and doesn't work)

So, my question is, how would I get access to the `RequestFactory` for making remote calls in Seraph?

When using the below code, if using `ComponentLocator` approach it returns null, and when using Dependency Injection it tells me the class couldn't be instantiated

```
Caused by: com.atlassian.seraph.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to instantiate class 'com.example.confluence.GluuAuthenticator' : java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.confluence.MyCustomAuthenticator
        at com.atlassian.seraph.config.SecurityConfigImpl.configureClass(SecurityConfigImpl.java:325)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.config.SecurityConfigImpl.configureAuthenticator(SecurityConfigImpl.java:258)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.config.SecurityConfigImpl.<init>(SecurityConfigImpl.java:194)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.config.SecurityConfigFactory.loadInstance(SecurityConfigFactory.java:56)
        ... 131 more
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.confluence.MyCustomAuthenticator
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:427)
        at com.atlassian.seraph.config.SecurityConfigImpl.configureClass(SecurityConfigImpl.java:320)
        ... 134 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.example.confluence.MyCustomAuthenticator.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
```

### ... 135 more

Here's the code so far

Targeting `Confluence 6.4`

```
import com.atlassian.confluence.user.ConfluenceAuthenticator;
import com.atlassian.plugin.spring.scanner.annotation.imports.ComponentImport;
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.Request;
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.RequestFactory;
import com.atlassian.sal.api.net.ResponseException;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.security.Principal;

public class MyCustomAuthenticator extends ConfluenceAuthenticator {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfluenceAuthenticator.class);
    private static final String CODE_PARAM_NAME = "code";

    @ComponentImport
    private final RequestFactory<?> requestFactory;

    @Inject
    public MyCustomAuthenticator(@ComponentImport RequestFactory<?> requestFactory) {
        this.requestFactory = requestFactory;
    }

    public Principal getUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        log.debug("SMAuthenticator::getUser(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)");
        Principal user = super.getUser(request, response);
        String code = request.getParameter(CODE_PARAM_NAME);

        if (user != null) {
            log.debug("User is already logged in: " +
                    ((user.getName() != null) ? user.getName() : "<None>") );
            return (Principal) user;
        }

        if (code == null) {
            log.debug("User is not logged in, and there is no code found in query params, will redirect to gluu");
            return (Principal) user;
        }


        log.info("User is not logged in, but code is found in the query params. Will start the flow to create the user, " +
                "starting with verifying the code: " + code);

        try {
            String s = requestFactory
                    .createRequest(Request.MethodType.GET, "http://scooterlabs.com/echo")
                    .addBasicAuthentication(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, "fooooo")
                    .execute();
            log.info("results: " + s);
        } catch (ResponseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return (Principal)user;
    }
}
```

`ComponentLocator` approach is simply

```
ComponentLocator.getComponent(RequestFactory.class);
```

but like, i said, always returns null  also tried `PluginSettingsFactory.class` and it also returns null

---

**EDIT**

Re-reading the [Seraph article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/single-sign-on-integration-with-the-atlassian-stack-794495126.html), I realized that dependency injection is not available to Seraph and there are a few caveats when looking for other Components (like `RequestFactory`).

Which leads to

```
RequestFactory requestFactory = (RequestFactory)ContainerManager
        .getComponent("requestFactory");
```

However, now the error has changed to

```
com.atlassian.spring.container.ComponentNotFoundException: Failed to find component: No bean named 'requestFactory' is defined
```

Also tried

```
RequestFactory requestFactory = (RequestFactory)ContainerManager
        .getInstance()
        .getContainerContext()
        .getComponent(RequestFactory.class);
```

with no luck either, says it can't be found

I CAN get other components though, for example using the example found here, works fine

```
SpaceManager spaceManager = (SpaceManager) ContainerManager.getComponent("spaceManager")
```

Answer (score 0):

### I managed to find an alternate solution to communicate with an external service

---

So, a few things for those looking at this:

1. Seraph requires any java jar, not specifically a atlassian-plugin
2. You can use any method you wish to communicate with the outside world

---

Saying that, you can use the build in `HttpUrlConnection` in `Java`. Its super gross to use but works perfectly. I'd abandon the idea of using `SAL` inside of `seraph` if someone finds this thread

Here's an example to get started:

```
try
    {
      // create the HttpURLConnection
      url = new URL(desiredUrl);
      HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      
      // just want to do an HTTP GET here
      connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
      
      // uncomment this if you want to write output to this url
      //connection.setDoOutput(true);
      
      // give it 15 seconds to respond
      connection.setReadTimeout(15*1000);
      connection.connect();

      // read the output from the server
      reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
      stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

      String line = null;
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
      {
        stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
      }
      return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
      throw e;
    }
```

Copy/pasta from

https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/java/how-open-url-read-contents-httpurl-connection-java

But you can find many examples online on how to use this